# How do I uninstall wine when I don't know how it was installed?

Tags: macos, wine

It was not installed with Homebrew, nor does a `.wine` file exist in my home directory. I don't remember when or how I installed it, but it's running and using up large amounts of CPU on my machine, and I'd like to remove it for good.

Comment: Are there multiple users on your machine?

Answer (score 3):

The `wine` project has an excellent [Wiki article specific to macOS](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS).  It includes how to remove `wine` from your macOS system, but basically there are a few ways to uninstall `wine`

MacPorts:

```
sudo port uninstall --follow-dependencies wine
```

Homebrew:

```
brew rm wine && brew rm $(join <(brew leaves) <(brew deps wine))
```

Source:

```
sudo make uninstall
rm -rf /src/wine              #Remove the source
rm -rf $HOME/.wine            #Remove pseudo C: and registry entries
rm -rf $HOME/.local           #Remove desktop menu entries and icons
```

You can attempt any of these methods without fear that if you didn't install using that method, there won't be adverse affects to your system.

Comment: Thanks. I found this page on Google too, but no use. I wish I knew how it got on my system in the first place.

Comment: What do you get if you issue the command `which wine`

Comment: I don't get anything

Comment: Then it's not in your path and probably no longer there.

Comment: I will check the next time I start up my machine. I force quit earlier